# Find only destination of symlink

Tags: command-line, symlink

For use in a shell-script, I'm looking for a commandline-way to get the destination of a symbolic link. The closest I've come so far is `stat -N src`, which outputs `src -> dst`. Of course I could parse the output and get `dst`, but I wonder if there is some direct way of getting the destination.

Comment: Actually wanting `src -> dst` as the output, hence finding this question, I found that `stat -N src` didn't work, but that `stat -c"%N" src` came close (RHEL7).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Another option would be to use the specifically designed command `readlink` if available.

E.g.

```
$ readlink -f `command -v php`
/usr/bin/php7.1
```

Comment: Use `readlink -f` if you want to know the _last_ symlink target and not only the _next_ one.

Comment: Good point! Forgot that.

Comment: Note that `-f` is a non-portable extension to GNU `readlink`.

Comment: When would readlink not be available? Thanks.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen readlink(1) was added to GNU coreutils in 2003, so these days you can likely depend on it on practically all systems using coreutils. (Cf. http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/src/readlink.c?id=2ae02ab5b91daa8dc94ac42496a3ee701c25d1ac)

Comment: You can probably rely on readlink these days, but you can't rely on -f on all *nix platforms...readlink is available on OSX but the -f flag is for specifying output format, and I don't see an equivalent for following all symlinks.

Comment: `readlink` can give trouble in scripts, it return the destination of the link, relative to the link. `readlink -f` only gives the final destination. If you where looking to copy the symlink and its destination in the script, the symlink will break if it was pointing to another symlink. The intermediate will be missing.

Answer (score 19):

On Mac OS X and FreeBSD/NetBSD/etc. it's:

```
stat -f %Y <filename>
```

More generically I guess the solution is (stat --printf=%N uses weird quotes):

```
ls -l b | sed -e 's/.* -> //'
```

Example:

```
# ln -s a b
# stat -f %Y b
a
```

Another method is:

```
# find b -maxdepth 0 -printf %l
a#
```

The last line is mangled because it has no newline, but that is fine if you need the result in a variable, like so

```
# f=$(find b -maxdepth 0 -printf %l)
# echo $f
a
```

The `-maxdepth` is needed to prevent `find` from descending into directories if `b` happens to be a directory.

Comment: I totally skimmed over, `stat --printf='%N\n'` is exactly what I want, weird quotes don't bother me, their the same quotes rm and ln --interactive use

Comment: This apparently isn't portable because on Linux, the GNU coreutils' stat(1) has different parameters and prints out `link -> dest` in the output. The find(1) solution should be checked if it's with GNU findutils or otherwise...

Comment: Please don't forget to quote your variable expansions, `echo $f` certainly does not produce what you expect when the symlink points to `/*` (yes it's possible)

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using GNU `find`: `find src -prune -printf "%l\n"`.

Answer (score 2):

`realpath` command of `coreutils` package,

as linked in `readlink` command's manual page.

---

for example:

```
realpath /bin/python
```

outputs

```
/usr/bin/python2.7
```

on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

On a system where I have no `readlink` or `stat` commands but I do have Python 2.x, I'm using a short script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    src = sys.argv[1]
    target = os.readlink(src)
    if not os.path.isabs(target):
            target = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(src), target))
    print target
```

Note that unlike `readlink -f` this may only follow one level of symlink.

Answer (score 2):

Portable pure Bash realpath

```bsh
bash_realpath() {
  # print the resolved path
  # @params
  # 1: the path to resolve
  # @return
  # &1: the resolved link path

  local path="${1}"
  while [[ -L ${path} && "$(ls -l "${path}")" =~ -\>\ (.*) ]]
  do
    path="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  done
  echo "${path}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Portably: no luck except using heuristics to parse ls -l output, or use `perl -le 'print readlink("some-file")'`

some systems have a `readlink` command, some with a `-f` option to obtain the absolute path.

There are various implementations of a `stat` command as a wrapper for the `stat`/`lstat` system calls. The GNU one is not useful in that regard, but zsh's builtin one is more so:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
stat +link the-link
```

Still with zsh, you can get the absolute path of a file (removes every symlink component) with the `:A` modifier (applies to variable expansion, history expansion and globbing:

```
~$ gstat -c %N b
`b' -> `a'
~$ var=b
~$ echo $var:A
/home/me/a
~$ echo b(:A)
/home/me/a
~$ echo ?(@:A)
/home/me/a
```

Answer (score 0):

Added a pure sh version, hoping it to be more portable if `bash` is not installed :

```sh
$ cat ./realpath.sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

bash_realpath() {
  # print the resolved path
  # @params
  # 1: the path to resolve
  # @return
  # &1: the resolved link path

  for path;do
    while [ -L "${path}" ]
    do
      path="$(\ls -l "${path}" | awk '{print $NF}')"
    done
    which "${path}"
  done
}

bash_realpath "$@"
```

Use case :

```sh
$ ./realpath.sh $(which gcc python)
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-6
/usr/bin/python2.7
```