# ln: create symlink using another symlink

Tags: ln

Let's suppose I have one file and one directory:

```
$ ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxr-x. 2 user user 4096 Oct  8 09:53 dir
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user    0 Oct  8 09:53 file
```

I created a symlink to `file` called `symlink1`, and a symlink to `dir` called `dirslink1`:

```
$ ls -l
drwxrwxr-x. 2 user user 4096 Oct  8 09:53 dir
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user    3 Oct  8 10:03 dirslink1 -> dir
-rw-rw-r--. 5 user user    0 Oct  8 09:53 file
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user    4 Oct  8 09:53 symlink1 -> file
```

Now I created symlinks to `symlink1` using `ln -s` and `ln -sL`:

```
$ ln -s symlink1 symlink2
$ ln -sL symlink1 symlink3
$ ln -s dirslink1 dirslink2
$ ln -sL dirslink1 dirslink3
```

Now, as far as I understand, `symlink3` should point to `file` and `dirslink3` should point to `dir`. But when I check it, none of the `symlink[23]` and `dirslink[23]` points to the original file or dir:

```
$ ls -l
drwxrwxr-x. 2 user user 4096 Oct  8 09:53 dir
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user    3 Oct  8 10:03 dirslink1 -> dir
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user    9 Oct  8 10:03 dirslink2 -> dirslink1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user    9 Oct  8 10:03 dirslink3 -> dirslink1
-rw-rw-r--. 5 user user    0 Oct  8 09:53 file
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user    4 Oct  8 09:53 symlink1 -> file
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user    8 Oct  8 09:54 symlink2 -> symlink1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 user user    8 Oct  8 09:54 symlink3 -> symlink1
```

The question is: Is it possible/How do I create a symlink to the original file using another symlink?

Comment: Related: [*Find only destination of symlink*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47710/15654)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-L` only works with hard links; as [specified in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ln.html):

> If the **-s** option is specified, the **-L** and **-P** options shall be silently ignored.

If you have `readlink` you can use that:

```
ln -s -- "$(readlink symlink1)" symlink4
```

If your `readlink` supports the `-f` option, you can use that to fully canonicalise the target (*i.e.* resolve all symlinks in the target’s path, if the target symlink includes other symlinks).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `cp -P` to make a copy of a symlink:

```
cp -P symlink2 symlink3
```

(assuming `symlink3` doesn't already exist as a directory or symlink to directory, see the `-T` option with GNU `cp` for those cases).

Beware that if the target of the symlink is relative, the above would probably result in a broken link if the copy is not in the same directory as the original.

With `zsh`,

```
ln -s -- symlink2(:P) symlink3
```

Would create `symlink3` as a symlink to the full canonical (symlink-free) path of `symlink2`, like `ln -s -- "$(readlink -f symlink2)" symlink3` but more reliable in that it would still work correctly if that path ended in newline characters.

Same caveat as above and same work around with GNU `ln`.